# How to specify zoom in url to maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps

I create a URL to google maps formatted like this:
  https://maps.google.com/?q=48.8567,2.3508&z=10

where I pull the coordinates from a database. With the new Map deployed recently (?) this does not work anymore. The map centers at the correct coordinates but not with the correct zoom level. Always displays with maximum zoom.

Does anyone know how to specify a zoom level?

Note that I'm not interested in obtaining an image: I want the full application, but initialized at the given coordinates+zoom.

Thanks. Pierre

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I don't get maximum zoom either, seems like it is at zoom=10 (on the [link you provided](https://maps.google.com/?q=48.8567,2.3508&z=10).

Comment: When I'm using the new Map, the link gets rewritten to: https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=48.8567%2C2.3508&data=!1m4!1m3!1d3278!2d2.3508!3d48.8567!4m14!2m13!1m12!3m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m2!3d48.8567!4d2.3508  Does that also occur for you?

Answer (score 0):

With the new Google Maps, I solved my problem by writing the URL as

https://maps.google.com/?ll=48.8567,2.3508&z=10

This URL gets rewritten as:

https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d354823!2d2.3508!3d48.8567

This generates a map centered at the coordinates given and with the zoom level specified. It also works in the previous generation of the application (where the URL does not get rewritten).

I could not find how to add a marker to those coordinates.